# (Closed) Conway's Game of Life not updating correctly (Python)

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

This is a snippet of code from Conway's Game of Life simulation made with Python. It's pretty simplistic for the purpose of checking whether it works - and it doesn't. Cannot figure out why, but as far as I can tell, it's something with the updating.

Would appreciate any input as to why it updates the way it does:

Gif in pygame (same code):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upuc5.jpg
Not updating correctly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb6tV.jpg

```
import pprint,random
#here we make the initial board, 6x6
board = []
for y in range (6):
    row = []
    for x in range (6):
        row.append(random.randint(0,1))
    board.append(row)
#and display it
pprint.pprint(board)

#this function counts the neighbours for each cell
def neighbours(x,y):
    counter = 0
    neighbours = \
    [(x-1,y+1),(x,y+1),(x+1,y+1),\
    (x-1,y),          (x+1,y),\
    (x-1,y-1),(x,y-1),(x+1,y-1)]
    for n in neighbours:
        a, b = n
        try:
            counter += board[a][b]
        except:
            pass
#printed out the counter to check if it counted correctly (it does, as far as I could tell)
    if x == 4 and y == 4:
        print(counter)
    return counter

#function to make a new board based off the old one - basically, the updater. 
#here's where the problem might lie - but for the life of me I cannot tell where and why.
def new(board):
    new_board = []
    for y in range(6):
        new_row = []
        for x in range(6):
            n = neighbours(x,y)
            oldcell = board[x][y]
            #everything is set up to be according to the rules
            #(if dead(0) can only come alive with 3 alive cells
            #(if alive(1) can continue to live with exactly 2 or 3 live neighbours
            if oldcell == 0:
                newcell = 0
                if n == 3:
                    newcell = 1
            elif oldcell == 1:
                newcell = 1
                if n > 3 or n < 2:
                    newcell = 0
            new_row.append(newcell)
        new_board.append(new_row)
    return new_board

#displaying the board for 6 instances
for i in range (6):
    nboard = new(board)
    board = nboard
    pprint.pprint(board)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what's the problem, but you could simplify that inner logic to `newcell = int(n in (2, 3)) if oldcell else int(n == 3)`

Comment: @tobias_k That kind of simplification is really only good in a competition, where you might be judged by the number of statements used in the code. In virtually all other cases, having the logic be expanded like how the OP has done it is far better, for readability and debugging purposes.

Comment: @Xirema I guess that's a matter of opinion. When I see this line, I read "newcell is alive if there are two or three neighbors if the old cell is alive, otherwise if there are exactly three neighbors", which IMHO is much simpler to grasp than those 8 lines of nested if/else. But as I said, it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are somewhere mixing up x/y with y/x, but I can't pinpoint yet where...

Comment: I don't know if this is directly related to your problem, but the `try` in your neighbors function doesn't catch all out-of-bounds indexing. For instance,  `neighbors(0,0)` will first try to check `board[-1][1]`. This will _not_ raise an IndexError because negative indices are valid in Python. As a result, cells on one edge of the board will check the state of cells on the opposite edge. But not vice versa.

Comment: If you have random in your code and find it goes wrong, try capturing an instance, board in your case, and have a script to run that through

Comment: @Xirema If this was code golf, I'd use `int(n in [[3],[2,3]][oldcell])`; you see, I'm reasonable. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up rows and columns in your loops, effectively transposing the entire matrix with each new board. The loops should look like this:

```
for x in range(6):
    new_row = []
    for y in range(6):
        ...
```

Also, the bulk of your `if/else` logic in the loop could be simplified to a single line. Whether that's easier to read and understand or not is for you to decide.

```
def new(board):
    new_board = []
    for x in range(6):
        new_row = []
        for y in range(6):
            n = neighbours(x,y)
            oldcell = board[x][y]
            newcell = int(n in (2, 3)) if oldcell else int(n == 3)
            new_row.append(newcell)
        new_board.append(new_row)
    return new_board
```

---

As noted [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332094/closed-conways-game-of-life-not-updating-correctly-python/44332443#comment75668778_44332094), there's a second (though less obvious) problem: While your `try/except` to skip all the off-board indices was a neat idea, it does not catch e.g. `x-1` for `x` = `0`, as `[-1]` is a legal index in Python (indexing the last element in the sequence), making your board "wrap around" two of the four edges. Instead, you should explicitly check for the bounds of the board. If you want, you could make this another 'fun' one-liner:

```
def neighbours(x,y):
    return sum(board[a][b] for a in (x-1,x,x+1) for b in (y-1,y,y+1) 
               if (a,b) != (x,y) and 0 <= a < len(board) and 0 <= b < len(board[a]))
```

Of course, you can also keep your loop and just replace the `try/except` for the `if` check.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything works as it should. So much grief from such a small thing)

Comment: As for the simplification, I'll keep that in mind - it is, surprisingly, easier to read than what I usually compose. Understanding will some with practice)

Comment: For the wraparound, I've made like so (for, as fun as the one-liner looks, I've some trouble wrapping my mind around what's going on there):
        if a == -1 or b == -1:
            continue
before the try/except.

(cannot figure out how to format code in here :C)